# Why failsafe plugin requires both integration-test and verify goals?

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have the next **pom.xml**

```xml
<project>
   ...
     <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/dmg/*IT.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    ...
</project>
```

The problem is that when I'm taking off **verify** goal then the build is every time successful even if there was test failures.

And when I'm Taking off **integration-test** goal the integration tests simply do not run

Why failsafe plugin requires both integration-test and verify goals?

Comment: What are you using such an extreme old version of maven-failsafe-plugin. The current version is 2.17...Furthermore the includes is not necessary cause these are the defaults.

Comment: This includes is necessary because i need to run only IT which is in **dmg** package and thank you... I didn't know about version))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Maven Failsafe plugin reference you can find simple answer why build is always successful

> ```
> failsafe:integration-test runs the integration tests of an application.
>   failsafe:verify verifies that the integration tests of an application passed.
> ```

Without **verify** goal test results are not checked at all(but they are executed), so failsafe plugin requires integration-test goal to run tests, and verify to "verify" their results.

Comment: but doesn't **verify** phase includes the **integration-test** phase? Why should I write both? The spec says that verify is after integration-test...

Comment: The plugin does not have it's own `lifecycle`. It is configured to execute `goals`. Those `goals` are bound to `phases`. The `phases` have place in the `default lifecycle`. That way maven knows which `goal` goes first. Why need two `goals`? 'Cause two are better than one. I might need to execute tests and then run some routine to publish results even if tests failed. I don't define `verify` execution and it's already done.

Answer (score 9):

In Maven there are two types of test runner plug-ins, Surefire and Failsafe and they both serve different purposes. (I mention Surefire here because I feel it helps explain and contrast different types of failure in builds.)

**Surefire**

Surefire is a plug-in designed for your pre-deploy tests, such as Unit and Component tests. Surefire is *guaranteed* to return a failure (and therefore break your build) if any of the tests fail.
You want this behaviour in pre-deploy tests because you want to fail the build early if your tests fail, and as Unit and Component tests don't (or shouldn't) have any external dependencies it's *safe* to fail a build there and then.

**Failsafe**

Failsafe is a plug-in designed for post-deploy tests, such as Functional and Smoke tests.
Failsafe, as the name implies handles failures *safely*, by always returning a success exit code (as you have experienced in your build).
The reason behind this is for post-deploy tests you *don't* want test failures to *immediately* break the build because you may have spun up infrastructure, or seeded some test data into the system, which needs clean-up before the build is failed.
Therefore Failsafe splits the failure checking into the `failsafe:verify` goal which happens in the `verify` phase.

If you run Maven without parameters (assuming the normal `jar` lifecycle) you'll notice a phase between `integration-test` and `verify` called, `post-integration-test`. *This* is the phase which was designed for the tear down of any infrastructure or test data you may have injected into the system to run the tests.

```sh
... pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, ...
```

The phase before `integration-test`, `pre-integration-test` is designed for the said seeding and infrastructure creation.

To sum it all up, with pre-deploy tests you want to fail the build as early as possible, and so `surefire` guarantees this by exiting with a failure.

Whereas with post-deploy tests there are often external dependencies which need clean-up before you fail the build. For example in Kubernetes you may want to issue a rollback of the deploy and so `failsafe:integration` always returns a build success to guarantee you can perform the clean-up before failing the build by checking the status with `failsafe:verify`.

(The currently accepted answer just quotes the manual and doesn't explain why there are two commands and there are differences which is why I feel this answer is needed.)